# How to auto insert row with 2 tables using MySQL event?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create auto (event) insert row function from `users` to `user_balance` table. I thought about creating PHP Cron system on my domain server, but using MySQL event will be more efficient. Code below is an example how it should work.

```
INSERT INTRO a.user_balance (a.user_id, a.account_balance) FROM b.users VALUES (b.id, b.account_balance) WHERE b.account_balance > 0

Edit event > Execute every: 1 MONTH


users

| id | account_balance |
|  1 |           10.50 |
|  5 |            2.80 |


user_balance

id              | user_id | account_balance | date_added        |
AUTO_INCREMENT  |       1 |           10.50 | CURRENT TIMESTAMP |
                |       5 |            2.80 | CURRENT TIMESTAMP |
```

So from table `users` I want to detect if `account balance > 0`, then insert new row to `user_balance` table. BUT **every first day of the month**.

Current `INSERT` doesn't work at all. How I can fix this `INSERT`?

Comment: Do you just need help with the SQL for the INSERT, or is there something specific about the event you need help with too?

Comment: @Rup Just solve the problem with INSERT.

Comment: You forgotten the `SELECT` keyword in your query.. i voteclosed "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct version of your [INSERT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) SQL would be:

```
INSERT INTO user_balance (user_id, account_balance)
SELECT  id, account_balance
  FROM  users
  WHERE account_balance > 0
```

i.e.

- you don't need the a/b table specifiers in this case; if you did, you'd specify them as `FROM users b` or `FROM users AS b`
- you don't use `VALUES` in this case: you write a `SELECT` instead, and the `SELECT` should be runnable on its own without the `INSERT INTO` to test its syntax
- (you have a type 'INTRO' that you've just repeated in the comments - should be 'INTO')